# Add leading zeros/text to aphanumeric column in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working with area ID's to create especific filters for workers that has also have an unique id, these id's are generated automatically by the DB, where the first digits are employee especific and then the area code where some are ints and other strings.

For example:

```
981505 '9815 is employee id and 05 his area
1340A '134 is employee and 0A his area (aphanumeric are managers)
```

For numeric data I have no problem doing a `.NumberFormat = "00####"` but for aphanumerics I can't apply the same logic, I've tried doing an IF:

```
If Len(pd.Range("C2:C" & fi).Value) < 10 And pd.Range("C2:C" & fid).Value Then
    pd.Range("C2:C" & fid).Value = WorksheetFunction.Rept("0", 9 - Len(pd.Range("C2:C" & fid).Value))
End If
```

And also using VBA `WorksheetFunction` returns an `not optional` error:

```
pd.Range("C2:C" & fid).Value = WorksheetFunction.Text("00########")
```

What I need:

```
00981505 'Lead zeros
0001340A 'I need lead zeros for future records as id's fluctuate a lot ( i don't know what process goes in the DB for the ids
```

For the sake of speed and requirements I need to do it in VBA, any help?

Comment: Please, show the final result of what you need.

Comment: And what data you are starting with

Comment: Added what I needed, basically, I need to add leading zeros where ID's contain text values.

Comment: Not at my computer so can't test. Try something like `Value = Format("1234A","####@")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to go about this would be to disregard functions that are type-specific and utilize something more dynamic, like:

```
Dim endRow as long

endRow = pd.range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For fid = 2 to endRow
    If Len(pd.Range("C" & fid)) < 10 Then
        Do
            pd.Range("C" & fid) = "'0" & pd.Range("C" & fid)
        Loop Until Len(pd.Range("C" & fid)) = 10
    End if
next fid
```

This would left-pad your values in Column C regardless of its primitive type.

**EDIT:**

The reason you're seeing errors when trying to apply the same logic is due to the fact that you can't take a range value larger than 1 cell and apply functions like Len() to it. Once it's more than once cell, its type is strictly a range and ranges don't have Len(), it'll throw a mismatch error.

Comment: It worked 10/10, and the explanation was bery insightful as I'm a VBA newbie, thanks for answering!

Comment: Glad I could help!